# Using requestPermissions getting error message

Tags: java, android

Trying to request permission in apk 23 using this

```
requestPermissions(this,new String[]{permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 8);
```

and my android manifest has `access_fine_location` in it, but when I try to compile I get this:

> error: cannot find symbol
>                   requestPermissions(this,
>                   ^
>
> symbol:   method requestPermissions(GMGeolocation,String[],int)
>
> location: class GMGeolocation

I've tried pulling examples from all the other posts on this but it still gives me this error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's related code snippet

```
public class GMGeolocation {

public void GMGeolocation_Init() {

RunnerActivity.ViewHandler.post( new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   requestPermissions(this,new String[]{permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 8);

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Try and restore the current location from a cached value
    provideLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
    provideLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));



}});


}
```

Comment: The first parameter expects an Activity

Comment: forgive me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that "this" would work as I saw it in a different thread on here as part of a fix. Does it only work if it's in a specific activity?

Comment: Are you doing this inside an Activity or a Fragment?

Comment: Using `this` will only work if GMGeolocation extends `Activity`.

Comment: @vidulaj I believe it's an activity, I edited my first post to include it.

Comment: @DanielNugent I included the bit of code that has the request permission (it's shoved in there for testing atm) so instead of this, what would I need to put in then?

Comment: @EricBlackburn You can pass the activity context as a parameter to `GMGeolocation_Init()` method and then use that instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

you are not handling it properly, firstly you are requesting permission, then on the very next line using the location services while you can use it once permission is granted on `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) guide to implement it properly OR set your app target to 22 if you don't want to use runtime permissions

Hope it will help you